# Trust Income tax and distributions

Tags: united-states, trusts-and-estates, income-tax

A hypothetical person has an irrevocable trust fund set up for him when his/her parents die. The adult child is the sole beneficiary of the trust and the sole trustee. He has a general power of appointment over the money in the trust. He/she has the right to take money out of
the trust or leave it in there to accumulate. In one year the trust has $30,000 of dividend income and $20,000 of tax free interest income.

Can the adult child distribute $29,000 (and only that amount) from the trust, claim that the money is all dividends and then the trust will pay no taxes?

The way I see it, the trust will have $1000 of taxable income which will result in no tax due.

Comment: Have you looked over 1041 to get a quick estimate of the tax situation for the trust?

Comment: @JonCuster I have. I posted here to check to see if my understanding of taxes related to trusts is right.

Comment: I do not see how those numbers square with the calculation of DNI on Schedule B. Even supposing there was no tax-exempt interest, I don't see where the $1000 difference comes from.

Comment: @JonCuster Here is my thinking. The trust does not have to pay taxes on the $29,000 it disturbed. Hence, it only has $1000 of taxable income. A trust with a $1000 of taxable income does not have any taxes to pay. Is my reasoning wrong?

Comment: Check the instructions for Line 21 for the exemption - without knowing exactly how the trust is set up I can't say which number to use. But in no case is there a $1000 exemption. Also check Schedule B. I would suggest a visit to a tax professional.

Comment: @JonCuster You are right there is not a $1000 exemption. However,  I claim that a trust with only a $1000 of taxable dividends, assuming they are qualified, pays no income tax. Do  you  disagree with me?

Comment: Yes, yes I do. If line 23 on the 1041 is more than zero, you owe tax (starting at a 10% rate). Furthermore, you need to establish what the Distributable Net Income requirements of the trust are.